# Не могу удаленно подключиться к базе postgres

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

Имеются 2 VPS сервера, на одном сервере расположена база постгрес, а на втором сервере лежит сайт, в php прописал строку для коннекта к базе, в постгрес отредактировал 2 файла конфига для доступа к удаленке, но все равно нет коннекта.

***Ubuntu 7.04 server i386.***
Версия ***PostgreSQL 8.2***

### pg_hba.conf

```
host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5
```

### postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

### php

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=ип сервера где лежит база port=5432 dbname=имя базы user=юзер password=пароль");
```

Только дело в том что, если я создаю сайт на том же сервере гдк расположена база

```
$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=имя базы user=юзер password=пароль");
```

то все успешно подключается, но мне нужно чтобы база була на одном сервере, а сайт на другом, и по удаленке были обращения к базе.

Так как у мня старая версия постгрес то ufw не установлен, пробовал ставить не ставится, стоит iptables. Добавлял правила для открытия порта 5432, сохранял, ничего не меняется. Пробовал удалять iptables, тоже без изменений.

### Проверяю ип сервера откуда будет обращение к базе, тобишь с сайта на пострес

> nc -zvw3 ип сервера сайта 5432 Warning: forward host lookup failed for
> Unknown host [ип сервера сайта] 5432 (postgresql) : Connection refused

### Пробую проверить 80 и 22 порты, пишет что открыто.

> nc -zvw3 ип сервера сайта 80 Warning: forward host lookup failed for
> Unknown host [ип сервера сайта] 80 (www) open

Помогите в какую сторону капать, тех. поддержка отвечает что "Мы не занимаемся администрированием клиентских серверов. С нашей стороны порты не блокируются."

Comment: После изменения конфигов БД перезапускали сервис постгреса чтоб он перечитал конфиги?

Comment: конечно, я полностью сервер перезагружал

Comment: Просканил ip БД (ip взял из последнего пункта вопроса, вообще ай-яй-яй выкладывать ip бд) на предмет открытого порта 5432 nmap'ом:
PORT         STATE      SERVICE
5432/tcp    closed     postgresql
Если бы провайдер блочил, то я бы не получил данный статус. Проблема точно где-то на хосте, так что стоит еще раз чекнуть fw, конфиг бд и настройки хоста.

Comment: там нет бд) т.е хостер не блочит порты? а куда капать? на сервере где лежит бд там во первых не устанавливается ufw, там стоит iptables, но я его снес для проверки и все равно без него не работает

Comment: А БД как установлена, в Docker контейнере?

Comment: На выделенной vps кроме сети с белым адресом есть еще какие-то сети? Может быть можно связать БД с сайтом по локалке между vps?

Comment: в админке основной ип и еще есть

Comment: Тогда попробуй связать БД с веб по внутреннему ip, а лучше hostname, чтоб избежать проблем если там dhcp. Доступны ли vps по hostname из локалки надо уточнить в провайдера.
Если получится, то вероятнее всего я выше ошибался и провайдер все таки блочит 5432 порт на внешнем адресе vps.

Comment: а можно с вами в телеграме продолжить разговор?

Comment: сделал команду   netstat -tulpn
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     3 получается постгрес слушает только локалку, тогда что не так сделал?

Comment: хотя нет, я переустановил постгрес, и по новой конфиги поправил tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5432            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     3